# PHP Pegar valor de uma frase dentro do array

Tags: php

Pessoal abaixo tenho um código que verifica o ping em *MS* de uma *url* ou IP porem o que preciso é pegar o valor da media do resultado que esta dentro da `array [10]`

**Exemplo :**

> M‚dia = 74ms

Queria apenas o valor **74** em um `echo`.

Segue abaixo um código teste

```
<?php
function pingAddress($ip) {
    $pingresult = exec("ping  -n 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);
    if (0 == $status) {
        $status = "alive => ( ".print_r($outcome[10])." )";
    } else {
        $status = "fora";
    }
}
pingAddress("www.google.com");

?>
```

Comment: `$outcome[10]` é uma array ou é um valor da array?

Comment: @sam ele está pegando o valor da 11ª posição  da variável executada no `exec()`

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o resultado de `print_r(pingAddress("www.google.com"));`

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer um cálculo de tempo de execução usando o [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.microtime.php)

```
<?php
function ping($host, $port = 80, $timeout = 10) { 
  $tB = microtime(true); // inicia um valor de timestamp 
  $fP = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); // checagem da url pretendida na porta desejada por um tempo determinado
  if (!$fP) { return "down"; } 
  $tA = microtime(true); // inicia um segundo valor de timestamp 
  return round((($tA - $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms"; // calcula o tempo de execução 
}

//Mostrando o ping caso esteja executando se não exibe 'down'
echo ping("www.google.com", 80, 10);
```

Comment: Ficou bem legal como faço para checar por IP sem porta apenas pingar o ip estou colocando ip 192.168.50.17 onde quero pingar mais esta dando um errro  Warning: Missing argument 3 for ping

Comment: esse ip pelo cmd do windows  esta dando 7ms

Comment: Ola @Erlon Charles

Comment: Quando você da um ping no CMD, mesmo sem colocar a porta você está acessando a porta 80, então você pode setá-la como default definindo `function ping($host, $port = 80, $timeout = 10) { `. dessa forma basta colocar `ping('www.google.com')`